# Mongo DB insert into a sub document if sub document value doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm very new to mongodb and i'm a little lost.

I have mongo db collection that looks like this :

```
  ({
    _id:id ,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    name:name,
    friends : [{name:1,children:[{name:sarah,age:12}]}],
    dogs : [{}]
  });
```

I would like to be able to insert a new element in the friends array if the name doesnt exist and a children element to that new array.

Pseudo code would be

`If Directory.find id.friends.name = true`

`update and add a new children document {name:"sarah",age:5}`

`else`

`make a new friend element with a new children subdocument`

After alot of research it seems that people are recommending the use of $exist but i can't find a way to use it in a sub document'

I've come up with this but it's not really working and i'm wondering how could i use that for my if else stament:

```
db.Directory.find({_id:id},{friends.name:"foo", {"$exists": True}})
```

For the actual query

```
db.Directory.update(
    { _id: id, 'friends.name': "foo" },
    {$push: {'friends.$.children':  {name:"x",age:"yy"}}}
)
```

And if it doesn't exist :

```
db.Directory.insert(
    { _id: id, 'friends.name': "foo" },
    {$push: {'friends.$.children':  {name:"x",age:"yy"}}}
)
```

But it's not really working , i'm not sure if there is something wrong in my formulas as it's a lot of trials and errors from research.
I also don't really know if that the proper way to do it as i couldn't find anything on a value existing on sub documents and was planning on trying to do a Find() search store the value and then test for true or false on the result in JS to make either of the update/insert calls.

Hope someone can help

Edit :
Let's say i want to add {name:john,age:15} to that friend name:1

```
friends : [{name:1,children:[{name:sarah,age:12}]}]
```

I'd like the output to be

```
friends : [{name:1,children:[{name:sarah,age:12},{name:john,age:15}]}]
```

or if name 1 doesnt exist

```
friends : []
```

make it so that it output

```
friends : [{name:1,children:[{name:john,age:15}]}]
```

Updated example :

case one :

```
friends : []
```

i add a new friend name "josh" with one child sarah , age 12 i get:

```
friends : [{name:"josh",children:[{name:sarah,age:12}]}]
```

This is perfect.

```
Now i add a new friend name 2 with children tom 15.
```

Nothing happens.

after , I want to add a new child to josh , timmy age 15

I get :

```
friends : [{name:"josh",children:[{name:timmy,age:12}]}]
```

And sarah disapeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to do it through [`Bulk operation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/), add one new friend through [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator and update friend through [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, update it after you making your question more clearly.

```
var bulk = db.Directory.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// if `friends` is `[]`, push the empty children firstly through addToSet
bulk.find({_id: id, 'friends.name': {$exists: false}}).updateOne(
     {$addToSet: {friends: {name: 1, children: []}});

// if we find the match friend, update this one through `$set`
bulk.find({_id: id, 'friends.children.name': 'john'}).updateOne(
    {$set: {'friends.$.children': {name: 'john', age: 22}}});

// if we cannot find match friend, insert the new one through `$addToSet`
bulk.find({_id: id, 'friends.children.name': {$ne: "john"}}).updateOne( 
    {$addToSet: {'friends.0.children': {name: 'john', age: 12}}});

bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, "nameinput" can be a js(string)variable right? Also,Does the first expression push the new element{name:x,age:yy} to the friends.name=name childrens input array ( user can have multiple childrens) ?

Comment: @user697, yes, the "nameinput" could be a js(string)variable. the `$set` just update the old friend of name is 'nameinput'. whereas the `addToSet` will add new friend to `friends` array, only the value inserted does NOT exists in the `friends` array.

Comment: hey , i've suceeded in implementing bulk on meteor after alot of hardship but it's seems there is an issue with the mongo formula that i can't find because it's actually adding a new "friends" array at the end of my main element instead of updating the children.. would oyu know why ? ( i've updated the post in case i wasn't clear)

Comment: @user697, you mean `{$addToSet: {'friends.0.children': {name: 'john', age: 12}}}` does not work? could you please give me some examples ? because I test it work well in my test data.

Comment: @user697, wow, you make me so confused, which you describe now is different with what you said in you question... so sad... or you did not give all information in your question.

Comment: @user697, please attention, one question of SO is for one issue only, if you have multiple questions please ask different questions.

Comment: I've updated my question answer. Sorry maybe i explain myself poorly english not my main language. It's the same question from the beginning that's why i was thinking of using " $push" but i thought addtoset was the same.

Comment: @user697, $push will push the element into array anyway. whereas, $addToSet will push element to array only if there is no duplicate element in this array. I highly recommend you to read the doc https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/ carefully

Comment: but add to set is not really what i want then, i guess i will look for other methods.  If friends.name $exist , then push new children to children array. so user can have multiple children.