# Pushing into sub document array inside by element

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have mongo db collection that looks like this :

```
({
  _id:id ,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  name:name,
  friends : [{name:"tommy",children:[{name:"sarah",age:12}]}],
  dogs : [{}]
});
```

I would like to be able to insert a new element in the friends array if the name doesnt exist and a children element to that new array.

If i'm adding a new friend named john with a child nathaly , i'd like the output to be

```
({
  _id:id ,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  name:name,
  friends : [{name:"tommy",children:[{name:"sarah",age:12}]},{name:"john",children:[{name:"natahly",age:20}]}],
  dogs : [{}]
});
```

If friend tommy already exist i would like just the children to be added to the children array and the output to now be

```
({
  _id:id ,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  name:name,
  friends : [{name:"tommy",children:[{name:"sarah",age:12},{name:"newchild",age:99}]},{name:"john",children:[{name:"natahly",age:20}]}],
  dogs : [{}]
});
```

I've tried so many things already it's impossible to [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716363/mongo-db-insert-into-a-sub-document-if-sub-document-value-doesnt-exist).

currently i'm trying a mix of everything

```
  // if `friends` is `[]`, push the empty children firstly through addToSet
  var bulk = Directory.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  bulk.find({_id: id, 'friends.name': {$exists: false}}).updateOne(
 {$addToSet: {friends: {name: name_var, children: []}});
  Meteor.wrapAsync(bulk.execute)();
  // then Since previous step create the children array for said friend only if it doesn't already exist i'm just trying to update said friend with the new child
  Directory.update(
  { _id: id,"friends.name": name_var },
  { $push: { "friends.$.children": {name:"sarah",age:12}
  }}})
```

(i've also tried with "friends.children" instead of "friends.$.children" but i just get a different error)

And this should cover my three case but i'm having issues and i'm wondering if i'm going the right way. Any of you guys have any idea because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874469/mongodb-push-in-nested-array) should at least work to add the children but it doesn't..

```
Errors : MongoError: The field 'friends.0.children' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: "0"} # when friends.$.children"

MongoError: cannot use the part (Friends of Friends.childrens) to traverse the element when friends.children"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to,

- Initialize the object you want to `insert/update`

The object can have multiple children inserted at once.

```
var obj = {name:"tommy",children:[{name:"ds",age:12},{name:"two",age:12}]};
```

- Initialize the [`Bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update).

The order of operations does not matter here.

```
var bulk = db.t.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
```

- Find and `update` only the children records that already have a sub document for the `name`.

use the [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) operator to maintain unique records, and [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) to add more than one children at a time.

```
bulk.find({"friends.name":obj.name})
    .update({$addToSet:{"friends.$.children":{$each:obj.children}}});
```

- Find and `update` those which **do not** have a sub document.

[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) the entire object if a document doesn't have one.

```
bulk.find({"friends.name":{$ne:obj.name}})
    .update({$push:{"friends":obj}});
bulk.execute();
```